# Programar para iOS em máquina virtual é viável?

Tags: ios, ide, mac, máquina-virtual

Sou desenvolvedor Android, mas agora vou começar a desenvolver também para IOS.

Fica funcional programar para iOS em uma máquina virtual? Ou tenho que comprar um Mac mesmo?

Comment: Se por máquina virtual você está se referindo a uma virtualização completa, como VirtualBox, recomendo fortemente que abandone essa idéia. Na minha experiência, a performance é sofrível. Compilar no Xcode deve virar um pesadelo. Se você tiver qualquer acesso a um Mac rodando ESXi e se referir a uma instância virtual (guest) do macOS rodando dentro do hypervisor, a conversa é bem diferente.

Comment: A menos que você tenha várias horas livres e bastante disposição pra aprender algo novo; conheça um pouco sobre kernel, SSDT, DSDT (ACPI), EFI, goste de mexer com hardware e esteja disposto também a caçar peças bem específicas no MercadoLivre ou eBay, nem considere a hipótese de Hackintosh. Ao menos não pra algo sério e crítico como **trabalho**.

Comment: Pelo que pude perceber, a muitas controvérsias sobre ser possível ou não ser possível, ou ser viável ou não ser viável trabalhar com VM ou hack. Preciso de algo que não me deixe na mão, pois é muito arriscado gastar uma grana em um equipamento novo e não conseguir o resultado esperado... Por enquanto tô achando que a melhor solução é comprar um Mac mesmo :/

Comment: Pessoalmente, também recomendo que você compre um Mac. Se preço é um problema, sugiro um MBP 13/15" Early/Late 2013. Você acha por valores relativamente atrativos em anúncios de usados como OLX e eles ainda duram um tempo. Exceto pela placa de vídeo, você provavelmente achará um MBP com specs muito similares ao que descreveu. Quanto ao Windows, você pode sempre rodar seu Windows em [Bootcamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)) ou, no caso de possuir um Mac, legalmente executar o macOS em um hypervisor sem muita perda de performance.

Comment: Não há controvérsias, as informações objetivas estão postas. Opiniões sempre podem ser dadas e parecer que se cria uma controvérsia, mas é só seguir o que se sabe de fato. Se será bom pra você, só testando. Nenhuma pessoa aleatória na internet poderá dizer o que é bom no seu caso.

Comment: Já fiz isso mas com a máquina virtual (vmware) em note separado do de desenvolvimento (core i7 8gb ram). Funcionou bem e deu pra debugar tranquilo.

Comment: @RafaelSilva acha que precisa de complementações nas respostas, ou já está bom?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pode ser que tecnicamente até consiga, mas a licença não permite fazer isso. Só é possível rodar um simulador de iOS e gerar a aplicação de uma máquina da Apple. Você pode até usar uma VM, mas ele tem que estar rodando em um Mac.

É possível usar algum serviço que lhe forneça uma VM rodando em Mac. O Visual Studio Enterprise fornece alguma coisa, tem outros serviços de nuvem de Mac. Veja:

- [Xamarin Test Cloud](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Mac in Cloud](http://www.macincloud.com/)

Terá uma experiência melhor com o Mac próprio. Se compensa só você pode dizer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Conceptual.md).

Comment: De fato, o maior impedimento para desenvolver nas plataformas da Apple sem um hardware homologado é o licenciamento. Simplesmente não é possível executar o macOS em hardware genérico **dentro do modelo de licença oferecido pela empresa**. As únicas alternativas legais são IaaS de Macs ou comprar seu próprio hardware. Não existe impossibilidade técnica para rodar um sistema operacional da Apple, desde que você tenha em mente os desafios e *possíveis limitações*, embora também não seja *fácil* ou quer dizer que *vá funcionar em todos os casos*.

Comment: Eu já fiz um teste de rodar MacOS em VM no Windows, só não continuei por causa da licença.

Comment: É, a licença é o maior blocker nesse caso. E quando falei do hardware genérico quis dizer usar o macOS em *bare metal*, ou seja, *Hackintosh*.

Answer (score 8):

Tanto em **VMs**, **Machine Cloud** (serviços de Mac na nuvem) ou em soluções **Hackintosh** o Xcode pode sim funcionar.

Entretanto, o que deve ser levado em consideração é o seu **objetivo final**. Seria apenas para *aprendizado* ou pretende *publicar* seus aplicativos?

Por que isso é importante? Por exemplo, para publicar os seus aplicativos na App Store um dos procedimentos é **gerar um certificado** de segurança **direto do seu Mac**. Se ele não for original você **não conseguirá executar este procedimento**.

Vale lembrar que todas essas alternativas **violam os "Termos de Uso"** da Apple. O contrato menciona que não compramos o software, apenas o “licenciamos”. E os termos da licença não nos permitem instalar o software em uma máquina que não seja da Apple.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Duas observações que podem melhorar a qualidade da sua resposta: 1) Tente utilizar sempre texto quando possível, linkando a fonte e realizando uma tradução livre do trecho de interesse. 2) Descreva mesmo que brevemente as alternativas do link do artigo que você citou, assim a resposta não é inutilizada caso o link se torne indisponível

Comment: Resposta reeditada.

Comment: Clouds também violam? Sinceramente pretendo comprar um Mac, mas o momento não é o ideal, então tenho que me virar com o que posso :)

Comment: Alguns fornecedores de serviço de Machine Cloud até mencionam em seus termos que fazem partições e se utilizam de bare metal (Hackintosh).

Comment: @AndreiaLopes estou curioso agora sobre o serviço PRO da Ionic, que prometem "em nuvem" também. Não que eu use sempre Ionic,mas para o caso especifico vou dar uma olhada. Infelizmente é investir alto em quase todos cenários para conseguir desenvolver, eu realmente queria um ambiente dev para iOS em Linux (ou windows mesmo) oficial da apple :/, mas ficaremos somente em sonho PS: para responder a uma pessoa especifica que tenha postado ou editado sua postagem use o `@<username>`

Answer (score 3):

Já usei VirtualBox pra testar como é programar em Swift, demorei um bom tempo pra conseguir fazer o MAC OS X rodar, na epoca acho que era o Yosemite ou El Capitan que eu instalei.

Depois de instalar demorei um bom tempo pra conseguir instalar o Xcode também, e quando finalmente consegui, ele funcionou muito bem, sem muitos travamenetos etc.

O meu maior problema era com tamanho da tela no virtualbox, não conseguia deixar a tela cheia e tinha que ficar usando barra de rolagem, além disso uns comandos do MAC que eu não conseguia achar no meu teclado "padrão" também eram um problema pra mim.

**Resumindo**

É possível programar em swift usando virtualbox sim. Porém é uma experiencia distante de ser agradável. Com relação a deploy do aplicativo, não posso afirmar com certeza mas é provavel que vc nao consiga fazer usando VM.

Minha sugestão é comprar um MAC usado pela olx, mercadolivre etc... E usar ele até conseguir dinheiro pra comprar um novo com uma configuração melhor.

Answer (score 2):

É possível sim, inclusive publicar o aplicativo. Tenho uma observação, apenas: Geralmente é uma onda imensa pra fazer o Mac reconhecer tua placa de vídeo. Com isso, tudo fica meio lento. Então o que eu recomendaria seria desenvolver em xamarin/react native e na hora q quiser fazer o deploy pra iOS, joga o código na máquina virtual (por “git pull” ou algo parecido) e compila lá.

Já li q dá pra virtualizar e conseguir usar a placa de vídeo, mas ainda não testei, irei testar daqui a uns dias. É usando “macOS-simple-kvm”. Dá um Google nisso q ele promete compartilhar bem todos os recursos com a máquina virtual, inclusive placa de vídeo.

A outra ideia seria fazer um hackintosh q também vai funcionar, mas pra esse caso teu hardware tem q ser compatível (processador Intel + placa de vídeo AMD)

Comment: Só complementando o que o André falou, eu já desenvolvi 100% por Vmware um aplicativo nativo em Swift e fiz a sua publicação (meados de 2019), assim como neste ano de 2021, fiz outro VMWARE para realizar a publicação de um app Flutter, sem problemas nenhum.

Answer (score 1):

Se você apenas criar uma VM e dentro dela usar um aplicativo de desenvolvimento, funcionará normalmente porém possivelmente pode ocorrer erro de Duplicidade se dependendo da plataforma de desenvolvimento que você escolher tiver que gerar outro emulador para funcionar...