# Desenvolver IOS em Windows

Tags: ios, windows

Para desenvolver uma aplicação IOS é necessário ter  um Mac? 
Possuo um Windows. Há alguma maneira de programar  uma aplicação ios  nesse sistema?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35337/101. Também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213185/101

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Desenvolvimento C# Mobile precisa de Mac?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35337/desenvolvimento-c-mobile-precisa-de-mac)

Comment: Existem alternativas. Unity 3D você programa o jogo uma só vez e roda em todo canto (não tão literalmente assim, mas quase). CodeNameOne, Gluon e TotalCross são alternativas para quem gosta de Java. Tem o "desenvolvimento híbrido", como chamam, com o Ionic que usa HTML5 para funcionar em diversas plataformas

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Desenvolvimento de app para dispositivos com iOS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/379985/desenvolvimento-de-app-para-dispositivos-com-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente não é possível. Você poderia tentar um "Hackintosh" - PC rodando uma versão modificada de macOS, porém é arriscado e os softwares de desenvolvimento e emulação são os mais chatos em relação ao ambiente. Comprar um Mac semi-novo no Mercado Livre é uma opção a ser cogitada.