# Desenvolvimento de app para dispositivos com iOS

Tags: ios, windows, osx, máquina-virtual

Funciona o desenvolvimento de app para dispositivos com iOS em VM´s com Mac OS debaixo de Windows? Algum problema de compatibilidade?