# É preciso de um computador MacOS para programar Swift 4 e ObjC?

Tags: swift, objective-c, osx, apple

Estou pesquisando bastante sobre programação de aplicativos para plataforma iOS, e todos os cursos online que encontro os computadores são da linha Apple. Para programar Apple, é preciso ter um computador da Apple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De maneira alguma, elas podem ser usadas em diversas plataformas. Essas linguagens não são "da Apple", são apenas mantidas pela Apple.

É claro que se você quer fazer algo para o MacOS ou o iOS complica um pouco fazer em outra plataforma. Não impede, mas dá um pouco de trabalho, especialmente para iOS que [exige um MacOS para publicar sua app](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/213185/101), mas [não para desenvolver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35337/101).

- [IDE para Windows](https://swiftforwindows.github.io/).
- [Visual Studio Code - Swift](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kiadstudios.vscode-swift?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Swift for Linux](https://swift.org/download/)

Sei que o mesmo vale para Objective-C, mas vai de Swift.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ah entendi, mas normalmente então, para programação de apps para apple é utilizado computadores MacOS ?

Comment: Outra coisa, então eu posso programar para apple ios, no windows ?

Comment: @VictorOCV exatamente, é muito mais fácil desenvolver na plataforma que você vai aplicar. Nos links falam alguma coisa sobre fazer algo para iOS no Windows. Com Swift não sei se compensa. Se fizer em C# aí já compensa um pouco mais, principalmente se for fazer para Android também (que de forma geral tem muito mais mercado). No fim precisará de um Mac para publicar por exigência da Apple. Tem aluguel de Mac virtual.